# merge replication taking longer with "Downloaded snapshot file '*****_9.bcp'"

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have a merge replication on sql server 2012 with five subscribers.
I reinitialised one of the subscribers to replicate all the data from the publisher but It takes the whole day downloading the snapshot. At the publisher I see the following message:

> > Applied the snapshot and merged 0 data change(s) (0 insert(s), 0 update(s), 0 delete(s), 0 conflict(s)).

And at the subscriber, on the view synchronization status:

> > Downloaded snapshot file '*****_9.bcp

This is taking forever now. I have 200 tables.

I have also run into the follwing error at the subscriber

> 2015-12-29 11:18:21.066 [100%] Skipping file 'VW_StudentHistcd097df8_324.sch' because it has already been delivered for a previous article or by a previously interrupted snapshot.
>
> > 2015-12-29 11:18:21.144 The schema script 'VW_Stockf5a261c5_325.sch' could not be propagated to the subscriber.
> >
> > > 2015-12-29 11:18:21.160 Category:NULL
> > >       Source:  Merge Replication Provider
> > >       Number:  -2147201001
> > >       Message: The schema script 'VW_Stockf5a261c5_325.sch' could not be propagated to the subscriber.
> > >       2015-12-29 11:18:21.160 Category:AGENT
> > >       Source:  "source name"
> > >       Number:  20164
> > >       Message: Unable to replicate a view or function because the referenced objects or columns are not present on the Subscriber.
> > >       2015-12-29 11:18:21.175 Category:NULL
>
> Source:  Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0
>   Number:  207
>   Message: Invalid column name 'stockID'.

At the subscribers, I don't have a data to be replicated to the publisher.
Thank you

Comment: The number of tables in replication is not as important as the size. How much data is there in the tables being synchronised? For a quick solution is possible to do backup-restore to catch up with the other nodes?

Comment: The View Synchronization Status dialog at the Subscriber is not reliable.  At the Publisher it says the snapshot has been applied, which means it finished reinitializing.  What happens if you perform an insert, update, or delete at the Publisher?  Does the change get replicated?

Comment: But the publisher database has already a lot of data and at least, it has to be replicated to the subscriber. And it has already been replicated to the other four subscribers. At this specific subscriber I am seeing no errors but the status shows "In progress"

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be with the VW_Stock view in the publisher's database.There was an invalid column. I updated that, take a new snapshot and make the subscribers download the new snapshot.

Thank you for your help